# Style Javafx tabs like a web tab

Tags: tabs, javafx, javafx-8

I saw [the tabs in this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm) in the Oracle website. How can I style JavaFx tabs to look like them? 
(Btw, is there a method to download that source code? I can't find the download link)

Generally I'm looking some free CSS styles which could be applied to JavaFx components for creating awesome view. I'm not a graphist and I can't make them myself. Certainly I don't mean that I'd like to use a WebView. I want styling just for JavaFx components. I would thank you if you also help me about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the JavaFX samples from the [JDK 7 download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Unzip them, and you'll find the css file in `src/DataApp/DataAppClient/src/com/javafx/experiments/dataapp/client/dataapp.css`

Comment: Ah! Thanks, you are right! There wasn't the compiled jar file so I couldn't find it.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665510/weird-corners-in-tab-headers-in-javafx