# Weird corners in Tab headers in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have weird corners in Tab headers. This is my Java code:

```
public class JavaFxTest1 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var tabPane = new TabPane();
        VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("NewTab");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Tab tab = new Tab("New tab");
                var content = new VBox();
                tab.setContent(content);
                var splitPane = new SplitPane();
                VBox.setVgrow(splitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
                content.getChildren().add(splitPane);
                splitPane.getItems().addAll(new TextArea("One two three"), new TextArea("One two three"));
                tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(tabPane, button);
        var css= this.getClass().getResource("test1.css").toExternalForm();
        var scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This is CSS code:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-padding:0 10 0 0;
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
}

.tab-header-area .tab {
    -fx-padding:4 10 5 10;
    -fx-border-radius: 10 10 0 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;
}
```

This is result in Linux (19-ea+3 for linux, JDK: openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-1, OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS):

[image]

It also doesn't work in Windows (Win7, java 18, JavaFX: 19-ea+3):
[image]

Comment: I cannot replicate your funky corners. Perhaps you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BasilBourque Please, see edit 2.

Comment: thanks for the example - worksforme win10, fx18+: each tab with rounded corner and the focus rect fully inside always (that is, looks the same just after adding and later)

Comment: @kleopatra Please, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that was replicated by JavaFX team. Issue is [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8284329)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is not a supported configuration for JDK 18 - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/products-doc-jdk18certconfig.html

Comment: Other related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690918/javafx-tab-rounded-corners/30692660#30692660